# Is this a Correct Derivation of $E=mc^2$?

Tags: special-relativity, mass-energy

I used Einstein's light box experiment in this. A description of the scenario, a box with a photon emitter is in space, out of reach from any gravitational field, I am floating in space watching the box as an inertial observer. The photon emitter emits a light beam, and the recoil causes the box to move in the opposite direction of the light beam. When the light beam hits the other side of the box, the momentums cancel, leaving the box yet again at rest. I modeled the situation using the following equations:

let $x$ = the displacement of the box

let $t$ = the time elapsed since the light beam was emitted

 let $s$ = the displacement of the light beam

let $l$ = the length of the box

Due to conservation of linear momentum:
$$
\frac{\mathit{E}}{\mathit{c}}=\mathit{m}\frac{\Delta\mathit{x}}{\Delta\mathit{t}}
$$
$$
\Delta\mathit{x}=\frac{\mathit{E}\Delta\mathit{t}}{\mathit{mc}}
$$
$$
\Delta\mathit{s}=\mathit{c}\Delta{t}
$$
The distance of the back of the box to the front of the box will always be the length of the box and since the light is traveling from the front of the box to the back:
$$
\Delta\mathit{s}=\frac{\mathit{E}\Delta\mathit{t}}{\mathit{mc}}-\mathit{l}
$$
$$
\mathit{c}\Delta\mathit{t}=\frac{\mathit{E}\Delta\mathit{t}}{\mathit{mc}}-\mathit{l}
$$
Rearranging:
$$
\mathit{mc}^{2}=\mathit{E}-\frac{\mathit{l}}{\Delta\mathit{t}}
$$
then because of conservation of energy, the energy of the box must remain the same; therefore, I can remove
$$
-\frac{\mathit{l}}{\Delta\mathit{t}}
$$
therefore:
$$
\mathit{E}=\mathit{mc}^{2}
$$
If this is wrong, how so?

Comment: $\Delta s = l - \Delta x$, you did it the other way round

Comment: Your re-arrangement is wrong. It should be $$mc^2=E-\frac{mcl}{\Delta t}.$$ But I still don't follow your argument for dropping the last term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is correct. The issues that jumped out at me first were

1. You use the non-relativistic expression for the linear momentum, rather than a relativistic one.
2. $m$ is the mass of the *box* but $E$ is the energy of the *emitted photon*, so they do not refer to the same object
3. I really do not follow your argument for dropping the $\frac{l}{\Delta t}$ term at the end. Other than the $E$ term, how are any of these terms related to energy (without assuming the result)? And if not, how are you able to invoke energy conservation. Even if you can relate them to energy, if $l$ is not zero then $\frac{l}{\Delta t}\ne 0$, so what you would have shown is that somehow energy conservation was failing here.

Comment: I think he meant relativistic mass with $m$. Not sure though.

Comment: @BrainStrokePatient maybe, but at the point you have written down a formula for relativistic mass you are quite close to assuming the result anyway

Answer (score 1):

It is wrong because the first equation is based on the fact that the momentum of the photon $\frac{E}{c}$ is equal in modulus to the moment of the box. It is right in the assumption that the box is at rest at first, and its velocity after the emission of the photon is small enough to allow the no relativistic expression for its momentum.

But your final conclusion, after dropping a term without reason, is that the energy *of the photon* $E$ is the energy *of the box* $mc^2$!